# RestSharp call to eBay oauth2 user token

Tags: vb.net, oauth-2.0, restsharp

I am trying to get eBay user tokens for my users using the identity api. I finally got it to work in Postman. Converted the call from Postman to a restsharp call from a vb.net test app. The Postman call works, the VB call returns "404 Not Found". Looked at the two calls using Fiddler. The only difference I can see is that the Postman call goes to:

"POST [https://api.sandbox.ebay.com/identity/v1/oauth2/token";](https://api.sandbox.ebay.com/identity/v1/oauth2/token%22;)
and the VB app call goes to

"POST [https://api.sandbox.ebay.com/identity/v1/oauth2/token/1"](https://api.sandbox.ebay.com/identity/v1/oauth2/token/1%22)

It would appear that somewhere the VB app is appending "/1" to the api url. Not sure where this is occurring as I can step through the code as it executes and don't see it.

Is there a property in RestSharp that might cause this value to be appended?

EDIT added code. This code is supposed to return a user token and refresh token from eBay. It is taken pretty much from Postman with mods to work with the latest version.

````
Async Sub RSGetCode(sCode As String)
        Dim client As RestClient = New RestClient("https://api.sandbox.ebay.com/identity/v1/oauth2/token")
        Dim request As RestRequest = New RestRequest(Method.Post)
        sCode = WebUtility.UrlDecode(sCode)
        With request
            .AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
            .AddHeader("Authorization", "Basic TXVycGh5c0MtNzYxNy00ZGRmLTk5N2ItOD..........................")
            .AddParameter("grant_type", "authorization_code")
            .AddParameter("code", sCode) 
            .AddParameter("redirect_uri", "Murphys_Creativ-Mu...........")
            .AddParameter("Scope", "https://api.ebay.com/oauth/api_scope/sell.inventory")

        End With
        Dim responce = Await client.PostAsync(request)
        'Dim responce = Await client.ExecuteAsync(request)
        Dim sR As String = responce.Content

    End Sub```
````

Comment: Add your code, RestSharp doesn't add anything to the URL unless it's instructed to do so.

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work by slightly reformating the code. See below.

```
    Async Sub PostRestCode(sCode As String)
        Dim client As RestClient = New RestClient("https://api.sandbox.ebay.com")
        Dim request As RestRequest = New RestRequest("identity/v1/oauth2/token", Method.Post)
        With request
            .AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
            .AddHeader("Authorization", "Basic TXVycGh5c0MtNzYxNy00ZGRmLTk5N2ItODc2OGMzZWZkYT..............................")
            .AddParameter("grant_type", "authorization_code")
            .AddParameter("code", sCode) '"v^1.1#i^1#I^3#p^3#f^0#r^1#t^Ul41Xzg6NEN.......................................")
            .AddParameter("redirect_uri", "Murphys_Creativ-Mu......................")
            .AddParameter("Scope", "https://api.ebay.com/oauth/api_scope/sell.inventory")
        End With
        Dim responce = Await client.PostAsync(request)
        'Dim responce = Await client.ExecuteAsync(request)
        Dim sR As String = responce.Content
    End Sub
```